# I am caputring web cam with cv2 after releasing and destrying it still access the camera

Tags: opencv

Following is the code
Note this is not full code but it is simlar to this. In orginal I have properly initiated frame and keys.

```
frame = cv2.videoCapture(0)
While True:
   _,cap = capture(frame)
   if key == 27:
       cap.release()
       cv2.destroyallWndows()
```

Comment: I am using falsk and redirecting to the original page and that is where it is not releasing webcam

Comment: It looks like you mixed `frame` and `cap`. It suppose to be `cap = cv2.videoCapture(0)` and  `_, frame = cap.read()`.